# Apache Commons IO - Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, io, apache-commons

Let me preface with saying that I have never used Apache Commons before, and my main goal is to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils in a Java project.

The problem I am running into is an error on the line:

`import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`

that reads:

> The import org.apache cannot be resolved

I have searched numerous Stack Overflow posts and posts on various other websites/forums, but cannot find a solution that has solved my problem.

As seen in the screenshot below, I do in fact have the commons-io-2.5.jar added to my project's Java Build Path. Any insight as to what I am doing wrong? Am I missing a step in the process to use Apache Commons?

[image: Project Java Build Path]

Comment: Does CTRL+SHIFT+T allow you to find `FileUtils`?

Comment: Pelase, post your code and imports

Comment: Did you occasionally delete common-io-2.5.jar or moved to another directory?

Comment: @mm759 : Yes, CTRL+SHIFT+T does allow me to find `FileUtils`.

Comment: @IvanPronin : The `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` is the first line of code I have, and since it has given me an error, I have not written any past it.

Comment: @simar : No, after downloading the zip from the Apache Commons website, I unzipped and moved the jar to the root of my workspace before adding it to my build path. It has since remained in the same directory.

Comment: You can try Project > Clean in menu.